# php - push array into array - key issue

Tags: php, arrays, key, push

i am trying to push multiple arrays into 1 big array, resulting in a 2 lvl array.

I got this set of arrays for example:

```
Array
(
    [cod] => ddd
    [denum] => ffffffffffffffff
    [descr] => ggggggg
    [cant] => 3
)
Array
(
    [cod] => fff
    [denum] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
    [descr] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
    [cant] => 33
)
```

But, after array push, i get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ddd
            [1] => ffffffffffffffff
            [2] => ggggggg
            [3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fff
            [1] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
            [2] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
            [3] => 33
        )

)
```

Basically this is what i want to do, BUT, if you notice after the push, the keys are forgotten, and converted to numeric.

This is what i want it to look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cod] => ddd
            [denum] => ffffffffffffffff
            [descr] => ggggggg
            [cant] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cod] => fff
            [denum] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
            [descr] => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
            [cant] => 33
        )

)
```

sample code im using:

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
       array_push($res_arr_values, array_values($row));
   }
```

Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: No one should be using `mysql_` functions anymore.  See [get array of rows with mysqli result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1501274/2943403)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't use `array_values` on your `$row`

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
       array_push($res_arr_values, $row);
   }
```

Also, the preferred way to add a value to an array is writing `$array[] = $value;`, not using `array_push`

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
       $res_arr_values[] = $row;
   }
```

And a further optimization is not to call `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` but to use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` directly.

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
       $res_arr_values[] = $row;
   }
```

Comment: 'the preferred way to add a value to an array is writing $array[] = $value; ' This is profound, thanks, reminding one self of that bit helps keep the program simple

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to go for

```
$arrayname[indexname] = $value;
```

Answer (score 7):

All these answers are nice however when thinking about it....
Sometimes the most simple approach without sophistication will do the trick quicker and with no special functions.

We first set the arrays:

```
$arr1 = Array(
"cod" => ddd,
"denum" => ffffffffffffffff,
"descr" => ggggggg,
"cant" => 3
);
$arr2 = Array
(
"cod" => fff,
"denum" => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg,
"descr" => dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg,
"cant" => 33
);
```

Then we add them to the new array :

```
$newArr[] = $arr1;
$newArr[] = $arr2;
```

Now lets see our new array with all the keys:

```
print_r($newArr);
```

There's no need for sql or special functions to build a new multi-dimensional array.... don't use a tank to get to where you can walk.

Comment: Thanks for giving a simple answer, for other readers. (Note that this is the same technique as accepted answer shows. It only looked more complicated *there*, because there it was answered within the context of the question. The key line in accepted answer is: `$res_arr_values[] = $row;`, identical to this answer's `$newArr[] = $arr1;`)

Comment: Indeed. I agree with every word. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $res_arr_values[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: `array_push` and this syntax is same.

Comment: `array_push()` **does** preserve keys `array_values()` does not.

Comment: I did not use array_push. I have remove array_values from the answer

Comment: the problem is not your example, it's your explanation. it's just wrong. do your research before answering.

Answer (score -1):

first convert your array too JSON

```
while($query->fetch()){
   $col[] = json_encode($row,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

then vonvert back it to array

```
foreach($col as &$array){
   $array = json_decode($array,true);
}
```

good luck

Comment: What benefit does converting to json add?  Answer: none. Sorry, this answer is not helpful to this Q&A.

Answer (score -2):

```
$res_arr_values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $res_arr_values[] = $row;
}


array_push == $res_arr_values[] = $row;

example 

<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);

Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
?>
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Comment: @user1248047 don't wanted to learn array_push function, he/she just to  know how prevent to replacing key values

Comment: There are multiple answers written a year before this one, that show the technique. I don't see that this answer adds any value. If I'm wrong, please add an explanation of what is new about this answer.