# PHP Associative Array in an Indexed Array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a `$string`:

```
'Name   Height  Weight
 John   177     142
 Jill   156     123
 Jacob  183     157'
```

And I'm turning it into an `$array` of the following structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        ['Name'] => 'John'
        ['Height'] => '177'
        ['Weight'] => '142'
    )
    [1] = > Array (
        ['Name'] => 'Jill'
        ['Height'] => '156'
        ['Weight'] => '123'
    )
    [2] = > Array (
        ['Name'] => 'Jacob'
        ['Height'] => '183'
        ['Weight'] => '157'
    )
)
```

Using the following code:

```
$rows = explode("\n",$string); //creates an indexed array of rows as strings
$headers = explode("\t",$rows[0]); //creates an indexed array of headers as strings
$rows = array_slice($rows,1); //removes headers from $rows
$array = Array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $array[] = array_combine($headers, explode("\t",$row)); //creates associative arrays for each row
}
```

However, I cannot access the associative arrays inside of the indexed `$array`

For example, this doesn't work:

```
echo $array[0]['Name'];
```

Even though `echo implode(', ', array_keys($array[0]));` gives:

```
Name, Height, Weight
```

I've tried many different ways of accessing the associative arrays inside of the indexed array, but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

So,

```
$string = "Name Height  Weight
John    177 142
Jill    156 123
Jacob‌​ 183 157";
```

Does not work, but

```
$string = "Name\tHeight\tWeight\nJohn\t177\t142\nJill\t156\t123\nJacob‌​‌​\t183\t157";
```

does...

So I suppose the question is: What's the difference? And how would I interpret the former string as the latter?

Comment: Did you `print_r($array)`? What do you see?

Comment: Ermm nope, the array your code produces does not have that format

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I see the array structure mentioned above (excluding the single quotes)

Comment: @HankyPanky How come that structure is what print_r() and var_dump() show?

Comment: https://eval.in/754774

Comment: https://3v4l.org/NhXGD works fine with `tabs` as delimiters. Make sure that delimiters in your string are tabs.

Comment: @HankyPanky Thank you for taking the time to test it out. However, the actual data I'm using (financial data that I can't post) has the structure shown above, I'm sure of that. Both print_r() and var_dump() confirm that. I'm not sure why your test isn't splitting the contents of each row by the tabs. Is there anything else you can think of that might cause $array[0]['Name'] not to work?

Comment: This post will help you to solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554799/php-push-array-into-array-key-issue

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for running that test. As I said to HankyPanky, I'm certain that the structure is correct and that the explodes are working properly. Both print_r() and var_dump() confirm that, as does implode(', ', array_keys($array[0]))

Comment: @SwetaParmar I'm not using array_push() or array_values(), I'm using $array[] = ...

Comment: AFTER EDIT: if your string comes from an outside source you should assert that it really contains \t (which is the `TAB` character literal in `PHP`); in your first code we cannot tell if you have multiple `SPACEs` or one `TAB` character; in the latter, after the edit, you can be sure it has the expected format. Are you *really* sure the input string contains `TAB` and not `SPACEs`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not produce that array structure but it can be fixed like this:

```
$string = 'Name   Height  Weight
 John   177     142
 Jill   156     123
 Jacob  183     157';

$rows = explode("\n",$string); //creates an indexed array of rows as strings

$headers = preg_split("#\s+#",trim($rows[0], "\n\r\t ")); //creates an indexed array of headers as strings, by splitting by any white space
var_dump($headers);

$rows = array_slice($rows,1); //removes headers from $rows
$array = Array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $array[] = array_combine($headers, preg_split("#\s+#",trim($row, "\n\r\t "))); //creates associative arrays for each row, by splitting by any white space
}

var_dump($array);
```

This produces output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Name"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Height"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Weight"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["Height"]=>
    string(3) "177"
    ["Weight"]=>
    string(3) "142"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(4) "Jill"
    ["Height"]=>
    string(3) "156"
    ["Weight"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(5) "Jacob"
    ["Height"]=>
    string(3) "183"
    ["Weight"]=>
    string(3) "157"
  }
}
```

The main ideas are that you must trim evey row string by any additional whitespaces and to split by the longest whitespace sequence.

Comment: Thank you. Give me a minute to wrap my head around this. In the meantime, any idea why print_r(), var_dump(), and implode(', ', array_keys($array[0])) are all suggesting that the array structure is correct?

Comment: Okay, any reason why preg_split() is a better alternative to explode()? Unfortunately the real keys I'm using have spaces in them, so this won't work for me :/

Comment: I chose regular expression split because the input string can vary. If it does not vary, and always have the exact same structure (i.e. only one TAB character) then is not a better alternative in your case.

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately, I need to use the tabs as the delimiters since the keys have spaces in them.

Comment: Then your code should work. I also have tested with tabs as other says and it worked. Try with this input string: `$string = "Name\tHeight\tWeight\nJohn\t177\t142\nJill\t156\t123\nJacob\t183\t157";`

Comment: @jeffbeene see here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/958fa6775f483025cfd3db15e87f24ade6d2c79c

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use following code it will work as your answer 
$string='Name   Height  Weight
 John   177     142
 Jill   156     123
 Jacob  183     157';

 $rows = explode("\n",$string); //creates an indexed array of rows as strings

$headers = explode("\t",$rows[0]); //creates an indexed array of headers as strings

$headers=array_filter(explode(" ",$headers[0])); ///t convert to space and filter remove empty element

$rows = array_slice($rows,1); //removes headers from $rows

$array = Array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row=explode("\t",$row);
    $row=array_filter(explode(" ",$row[0]));

    $array[] = array_combine($headers,$row); //creates associative arrays for each row
}

//print_r($array);
echo $array[0]['Name'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, what if I want spaces in my array keys? For example: "Person's Name" instead of "Name"

Comment: If you want to use that type of the header ["Person's Name"] then the logic is wrong from the start. We need to use diffrent logic for that explode \n will give you space separate string in single row.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems my problem is not having `\t` in the string, but I'm not sure how to "replace" tabs with `\t`, if that makes sense... See the edit to my question.