# How to save single row data coming from MySQL database in PHP variables?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is what I'm trying but I'm not sure it must be this way.
I wanna charge those variables to use them in my js function later

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $name = "";
  $lat = '';
  $lng = '';
  
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projectppy");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT name, lat, lng FROM customers ORDER BY ID DESC";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["name"], $row["lat"], $row["lng"]);
}

?>
```

Comment: You already have it in a variable as an array. But you can unpack it: `[$name, $lat, $lng] = $row;`.

Comment: What do you mean, "charge"? To use PHP data in JS you may want to use json_encode(). But that's unrelated to mysql

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be getting a single row but rather array of rows. Than you need this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59028348/285587

Comment: I just meant that I want to save it like <script> var name = "<?php echo $name;?>";      
      var lat = <?php echo $lat;?>;
      var lng =<?php echo $lng;?>;</script>    but first I need to get the data from my database and save it in php variables

Comment: Just NEVER EVER do that. Never output any data unencoded. Make it  `var row = "<?= json_encode($row) ?>";` then use `row.name` in JS. What's so hard with it?

Comment: okay, but anyway something is not working on my query I just need data from a row not all. It seems like my query and fetch are wrong

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for answering , helped a lot. I'm just starting learning and now I need to learn how to use the json you said, if you can show me or something would be great anyway until now I'm already happy